# NewtonSoft from XML to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

The question is not only to convert from XML to JSON. The question is how can I change the default conversion and produce the JSON I need.

Let me explain with an example

I received and XML with several formats. An example of this XML is something like this:

```
<root>
  <Data Name="Var1">Value1</Data>
  <Data Name="Var2">Value2</Data>
</root>
```

Using C#, I'm trying to convert to JSON in this way:

```
xmldoc = "<root>" +
           "<Data Name=\"Var1\">Value1</Data>" +
           "<Data Name=\"Var2\">Value2</Data>" +
           "</root>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmldoc);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

The result is:

```
{
    "root": {
        "Data": [
            {
                "@Name": "Var1",
                "#text": "Value1"
            },
            {
                "@Name": "Var2",
                "#text": "Value2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My question is how can I convert Data nodes as "Var1":"Value1" instead of @Name/#Text as result produces

Comment: I'm guessing out of [4000+ questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+xml+to+json) you could likely find your answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well, the very first of those question has exactly that answer that obviously OP already uses. But that didn´t help him/her much.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well, we can't expect people to go beyond the first hit when doing research, to be sure...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Definitely, both don’t understand the question. But it’s better to troll and assume you are smarter than all. Regardless, thank you for your time

Comment: @HimBromBeere Really? Have you understand the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add an intermediate stage between the XML deserialization and the Json Serialization. When you deserialize the XML to the class, create some new classes that will output to the JSON format you like, then implement some logic to create the JSON classes from the XML classes.